# Oracle JDBC Driver ResultSet PreparedStatement Throws ORA-009900 invalid SQL statement Exception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using Oracle JDBC Driver ojdbc6.jar. When executing a `PreparedStatement` the `ResultSet` is returned. However when trying to get details back of what has been saved, I am unable to get this and it throws an Exception.

Below is the code:

```
public Processor {

    private Connection connection;

    public Processor() throws Exception {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public int saveData(String name) throws Exception {
       PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(name);
       preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
       ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
       resultSet.next();
       String row = resultSet.getString("NAME");
       return resultSet.getRow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Processor processor = new Processor();
         int row = processor.saveData(new String("INSERT INTO NAMES (name) VALUES (nameTable)"));
    }
}
```

The url, username and password are setup but not shown in the code. I can connect to the Oracle database and persist the data. However, the problem arises when calling `resultSet.getString("NAME")`. The following Exception is shown:

```
ORA-009900: invalid SQL statement
java.sql.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
```

When executing the following code:

```
ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT NAME FROM NAMES"));
resultSet.next();
String name = resultSet.getString("NAME");
```

This works. I have also executed in the SQL describe `NAMES` and the name attribute is displayed as `NAME`.

The issue is something to do with the `PreparedStatement` object returning the `ResultSet` data.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:675)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Odscrarr.doODNY(T48COdscrarr.java:98)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:818)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleResultSetImpl.java:3711)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2799)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
at com.example.ProcessorTest.testExecuteInsert(ProcessorTest.java:14)
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace. I find it hard to believe a `resultSet.getString` would throw this error; I'd sooner expect it on execute

Comment: Pleas see EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

Your `saveData` method is the cause because an `INSERT` does not produce a `ResultSet`, so `executeQuery` will produce an error, as there will be no `ResultSet`.

Also you should only use `connection.prepareCall(String)` for executing stored procedures, not for other types of statements. For a prepared statement you should use `connection.prepareStatement(String)`.

Change your code to:

```
public int saveData(String name) throws Exception {
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(name);
   preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
   return preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

BTW: I hope you are aware that this method uses the parameter `name` both for the query and as the parameter for the query (which really does not make a lot of sense).

And finally, the `new String(...)` you do in your main is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually connection.prepareStatement(name) but it is preparedStatement.executeQuery().

Comment: I couldn't copy the code into the browser, so I had to write the code. I want to receive data that was inserted through the get() methods. I have shown the stack trace above.

Comment: I need to get the ID the unique identifer as the return of the result. That's why I need to get the details of the Result Set.

Comment: I'd suggest you post your actual code, because I have the feeling something is missing. However getting the generated ID with Oracle as not as simple as this. You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004128/obtain-id-of-an-insert-in-the-same-statement

Answer (score 0):

First of all this line of code

```
int row = processor.saveData(new String("INSERT INTO NAMES (name) VALUES (nameTable)"));
```

As you have specified that the method saveData() takes argument as String so there is no need of any new String(...) here and moreover you are using PreparedStatement so you can use parameterized query something like this

```
int row = processor.saveData("INSERT INTO NAMES (name) VALUES (?)");
```

Then you can use this statement in `saveData()`

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "name");
```

Finally you are updating the table not quering it so change this

```
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

to

```
return preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

One more thing you should be very specific about your method name. You should always name a method based on what it is going to do. Like `saveData()` here must be used only for saving data not querying the data as you were trying to do by using the `ResultSet`. If you want to retrieve the data then use some other method.