Oracle SQL insert into table from another table returning its ID and setting foreign key
This question is similar to others, but is specific to Oracle SQL and specific to the setting foreign key scenario, the combination of which comes with some limitations that other SQL dialects don't.
We are trying to migrate some columns/data from Table A to Table B. These columns already exist in Table B but obviously don't contain all the rows from Table A. After the migration the columns should be removed from Table A and instead a foreign key should be pointing to Table B.
I have already created the foreign key
ALTER TABLE A
    ADD fk_ID NUMBER(19);

ALTER TABLE A
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_ID)
    REFERENCES B (id);

Now I want to do something like (pseudo-code)
INSERT INTO B (
    apple,
    banana,
    orange,
)
SELECT
    apple,
    banana,
    orange,
FROM A RETURNING ID
SET A.fk_ID = ID;

But obviously this doesn't work.
I've tried googling but I can't seem to find any working solution. Any ideas?
EDIT
Here's an example of how the tables look like right now:
Table A



ID
APPLE
BANANA
ORANGE




1
50
50
50


2
null
60
70


3
50
null
80


4
40
null
null



Table B



ID
LEMON
APPLE
BANANA
ORANGE




1
20
50
50
50


2
30
50
50
50


3
40
null
60
60



Please note that:

Duplicates may occur across tables - e.g. the first row in Table A is identical to Table B when only looking at (ID, apple, banana, orange)
Duplicates may occur within Table B - e.g. the first two rows when only looking at (apple, banana, orange)
There may contain null values in both tables
The IDs are not sequential, but they are not globally unique across tables either

Expected result
Table A



ID
FK_ID




1
4


2
5


3
6


4
7



Table B



ID
LEMON
APPLE
BANANA
ORANGE




1
20
50
50
50


2
30
50
50
50


3
40
null
60
60


4
null
50
50
50


5
null
null
60
70


6
null
50
null
80


7
null
40
null
null



Takeaways:

Each row in A can be referenced to a corresponding row in B
Even though Table B already contained a row with matching values (1st row), table A still got the correct foreign key ID of row 4

I've previously thought of using something like e.g.
WHERE(a.apple = b.apple AND a.banana = b.banana AND a.orange = b.orange)
but I think this won't work because of the above example




Does this help does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499616/how-to-return-newly-inserted-record-column-value

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for tables A and B and the sample data in those tables; and the expected output after the data has been migrated. At the moment the question is very hard to answer because you have only given half the information and not provided any examples of what you expect to happen.

You have to do it two steps. Create B using a CTAS statement, then use an update or merge-update on table A to populate the FK key column using a query against B.

Here is another solution with PL/SQL, it requires that you add a column in table B to hold the id of the table A's row, it's a little bit more complex but it can be more efficient because the update the table A may take advantage of indexes on the ID columns. You can also optimize the memory consumption by bulk collecting by chunk if you have to handle a large number of rows. Once done you can drop the a_id from table B and the now unnecessary columns from table A.
create table t_b (
    a_id number(10,0),
    col1 varchar2(16),
    col2 varchar2(16),
    col3 varchar2(16),
    col4 varchar2(16), -- not in A
    id number(10,0) generated by default on null as identity primary key 
);

create table t_a (
    id number(10,0) generated always as identity primary key ,
    col1 varchar2(16),
    col2 varchar2(16),
    col3 varchar2(16),
    col5 varchar2(16), -- not in B
    b_id number(10,0),
    constraint fk_b foreign key(b_id) references t_b(id)
);

insert into t_a(col1, col2, col3, col5) values('a', 'b', 'c', 'A') ;
insert into t_a(col1, col2, col3, col5) values('d', 'e', 'f', 'B') ;
insert into t_a(col1, col2, col3, col5) values('g', 'h', 'i', 'C') ;
commit ;


declare
    type t_row is record (
        a_id number(10,0),
        col1 varchar2(16),
        col2 varchar2(16),
        col3 varchar2(16)
    );
    type   tt_rows is table of t_row ;
    v_rows  tt_rows;
    type   tt_ids is table of t_b.id%type index by binary_integer;
    v_ids   tt_ids;
begin
    select id, col1, col2, col3
    bulk collect into v_rows
    from t_a ;

    forall i in v_rows.first..v_rows.last
        insert into t_b values (v_rows(i).a_id, v_rows(i).col1, v_rows(i).col2, v_rows(i).col3, null, null)
    returning id bulk collect into v_ids;

    merge into t_a d
    using (
        select id, a_id from t_b
    ) s on (s.a_id = d.id)
    when matched then
        update set b_id = s.id ;    
        
    commit ;
end ;
/


You appear to want a two-step process to INSERT the rows into B and then use an UPDATE with a correlated sub-query to get the IDs.
Using something similar to @p3consulting's answer but without requiring a column in table b to store the primary key of a as you can correlate values from two collections and use the ROWID pseudo-column:
DECLARE
  TYPE a_row IS RECORD(
    rid    ROWID,
    apple  A.APPLE%TYPE,
    banana A.BANANA%TYPE,
    orange A.ORANGE%TYPE
  );
  TYPE a_tab  IS TABLE OF a_row;
  TYPE id_tab IS TABLE OF B.ID%TYPE;
  v_a   a_tab;
  v_ids id_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID, apple, banana, orange
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_a
  FROM   a;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. v_a.COUNT
    INSERT INTO b (apple, banana, orange)
    VALUES (v_a(i).apple, v_a(i).banana, v_a(i).orange)
    RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. v_a.COUNT
    UPDATE a
    SET   fk_id = v_ids(i)
    WHERE ROWID = v_a(i).rid;
        
  COMMIT;
END;
/

Then you can drop the unnecessary columns from A.
ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN apple;
ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN orange;
ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN banana;

Which, given the initial setup:
CREATE TABLE A (id PRIMARY KEY, apple, banana, orange) AS
SELECT 1, 50,   50,   50   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL, 60,   70   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 50,   NULL, 80   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 40,   NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b (
  id     NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  lemon  NUMBER,
  apple  NUMBER,
  banana NUMBER,
  orange NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO b (lemon, apple, banana, orange)
SELECT 20 AS l, 50 AS a, 50 as b, 50 AS o FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 50,   50, 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 40, NULL, 60, 60 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE A ADD fk_ID NUMBER(19);
ALTER TABLE A
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_ID)
    REFERENCES B (id);

Then after the PL/SQL block and dropping the columns the tables contain:
SELECT * FROM a;




ID
FK_ID




1
4


2
5


3
6


4
7



SELECT * FROM b;




ID
LEMON
APPLE
BANANA
ORANGE




1
20
50
50
50


2
30
50
50
50


3
40
null
60
60


4
null
50
50
50


5
null
null
60
70


6
null
50
null
80


7
null
40
null
null




If you have a particularly large set of rows and don't want to create large in-memory collections then you can use a cursor and limit the number of rows in each batch:
DECLARE
  TYPE a_row IS RECORD(
    rid    ROWID,
    apple  A.APPLE%TYPE,
    banana A.BANANA%TYPE,
    orange A.ORANGE%TYPE
  );
  TYPE a_tab  IS TABLE OF a_row;
  TYPE id_tab IS TABLE OF B.ID%TYPE;
  v_a   a_tab;
  v_ids id_tab;

  CURSOR c_a IS
    SELECT ROWID, apple, banana, orange
    FROM   a;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_a;

  LOOP
    FETCH c_a BULK COLLECT INTO v_a LIMIT 1000;
    EXIT WHEN v_a.COUNT = 0;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. v_a.COUNT
      INSERT INTO b (apple, banana, orange)
      VALUES (v_a(i).apple, v_a(i).banana, v_a(i).orange)
      RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. v_a.COUNT
      UPDATE a
      SET   fk_id = v_ids(i)
      WHERE ROWID = v_a(i).rid;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

fiddle

Thanks for the answer. I've updated the question now, I'm afraid the WHERE(a.apple = b.apple AND a.banana = b.banana AND a.orange = b.orange) style of logic is vulnerable to duplicates though

@Nermin Updated.
